# get a reversed sorted quickSort (descending order)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, quicksort

I have a problem with my code that hopefully someone here can solve. The code works with the quickSort algorithm but I want this specific part of the code to give me a reversed sorted quickSort list, so a list in a descending order. Can someone here help me?

```
def quickSort(L, ascending = True):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    if len(L) <= 1: return L
    smaller, equal, larger = [],[],[]
    pivot = L[randint(0,len(L)-1)]

    for x in L:
        if x < pivot: smaller.append(x)
        elif x == pivot: equal.append(x)
        else: larger.append(x)

    print('result: ', quickSort(smaller)+equal+quickSort(larger))
    return quickSort(smaller)+equal+quickSort(larger)


l1 = list([3, 2, -1, 9, 17, 4, 1, 0])

l2 = list([3.14159 , 1./127, 2.718 , 1.618 , -23., 3.14159]) 

l1 = mergeSort(l1)

l2 = quickSort(l2,False)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list isn't ascending, then the larger elements come before the smaller ones in the output. Don't forget to pass the `ascending` value into the recursive calls.

```
from random import randint


def quickSort(L, ascending=True):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return L
    smaller, equal, larger = [], [], []
    pivot = L[randint(0, len(L) - 1)]

    for x in L:
        if x < pivot:
            smaller.append(x)
        elif x == pivot:
            equal.append(x)
        else:
            larger.append(x)

    larger = quickSort(larger, ascending=ascending)
    smaller = quickSort(smaller, ascending=ascending)

    if ascending:
        final = smaller + equal + larger
    else:
        final = larger + equal + smaller
    return final


l2 = list([3.14159 , 1./127, 2.718 , 1.618 , -23., 3.14159])
print(quickSort(l2, ascending=False))
# [3.14159, 3.14159, 2.718, 1.618, 0.007874015748031496, -23.0]
```

It's worth noting that by not doing the sort in-place, without forming any extra lists, you lose a lot of the benefits of quicksort.  You should try writing an implementation that only swaps elements in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse all your comparison operators when given `ascending=False`.

Although, it would be simpler to use a wrapper on your function that reverses the list when given this parameter.

```
import random

def _quickSort(lst):
    print('Quicksort, Parameter L:', lst)
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    smaller, equal, larger = [], [], []
    pivot = random.choice(lst)

    for x in lst:
        if x < pivot: smaller.append(x)
        elif x == pivot: equal.append(x)
        else: larger.append(x)

    print('result: ', _quickSort(smaller) + equal + _quickSort(larger))
    return _quickSort(smaller) + equal + _quickSort(larger)

def quickSort(lst, ascending=True):
    if ascending:
        return _quickSort(lst)
    else:
        return _quickSort(lst)[::-1]
```

Output:

```
lst = [3, 2, -1, 9, 17, 4, 1, 0]

lst = quickSort(lst, ascending=False)

print(lst) # [17, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

### Sidenotes

In Python, we generally try to use uppercased names for class only, so avoid naming a list `L`, use `l` instead, or `lst`.

Also, to select a random pivot, using `random.choice` is a neater way than `random.randint`.